Comparing two dynamic ranges
I have the following summation table
Range 1 (expected output)



Responsibility Center
Authorized HC
# of Vacancies
Pending Approvals




County 1
26
1
2


County 2
7
21
1


County 3
53
35
1


County 4
53
35
0



Range 2



Create Date
Incumbent
Office Title
Responsibility Center




5/23/2024
John Jones
Housing Assistant
County 1


5/23/2024
Jane Joe
Housing Assistant
County 2


5/28/2024
Jim Jong
Housing Assistant
County 3


5/28/2024
Cang Cong
Housing Assistant
County 1



Basically, the pending approvals in range 1 need to be drawn from the responsibility center column in range 2. So, there are values for county 1 2 and 3, but not 4, so I don't expect any value to show up in that cell. The list in range two can be dynamically sized, so I'd prefer to not hardcode the range in if I can.
I tried the following two functions in column d, copy pasted down
in d2:d5
= countif(d18#, $A2)
=MAP(A5#, CHOOSECOLS(A18#, 4), LAMBDA(a,b, COUNTIF(a, b)))

both didn't work!
What I am trying to do is the formula
= countif(d18$D21, a2)

but to have the range dynamically sized

If range 2 is a single spill output, you can use =countif( CHOOSECOLS(A18#, 4) , $A2)  if A18 is where the spill formula is. Starting from where the formula is and choosing the 4th column to check against.

@MarkS. range 2 is generated from a previous filter function. Excel doesn't let me type in as you have written it

What is the region of your excel? What cell is the filter function in?

@MarkS. The filter function is in cell A18.

=countifs( index( A18#,,4) , $A2) This should give you what you need! The issue is choosecols is producing an array while countif/s is expecting a range, index can have a similar output but is treated differently, so this should work.

I dont think the given formula should work if both are array here. As is I have understood from the formula you have posted in your OP.

You could try using the following formula:


• Formula used in cell D2
=MAP(INDEX(A2#,,1),LAMBDA(α, SUM(COUNTIFS(α, INDEX(F2#,,4)))))


Another alternative using MMULT()


=MMULT(N(INDEX(A2#,,1)=TOROW(INDEX(F2#,,4))),SEQUENCE(ROWS(A2#))^0)


Using BYROW() without LAMBDA() construct with CHOOSECOLS()


=BYROW(--(CHOOSECOLS(A2#,1)=TOROW(CHOOSECOLS(F2#,4))),SUM)



how did you edit the question?

Using this Mardown_Generator the op had lot of unwanted spaces and non printable characters so it took me to clean.

Using Choosecols returns an Array in a countif / countifs function, which expects a Range, so this will result in errors.
However, using INDEX returns an array but can be used effectively the same way by skipping over the row #, like so, =Index( A18#,, 4)
Nesting the index within the countif or countifs will result in counting the "range".
=countifs( index( A18#,,4) , $A2)
